# Two Controls Bound To Same Property WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I've got a ListBox and a DataGrid where the ListBox shows a subset of the list of the DataGrid. I created the two lists that the control's are bound to separately, however both control's SelectedItem are bound to the same property in the view model. I need to have both controls select the same item when the user clicks on either control's items unless the user clicks on the DataGrid on an item that is not in the ListBox's subset (then the ListBox should not have anything selected).

I'm guessing since the lists were created separately they are not the same object so is there a way to provide some sort of comparison logic to the controls to select an item that essentially has the same name (or value or some sort of criteria)? If that doesn't exist then I guess the best way would be to create the subset list of objects from the exact same objects in the superset.

Comment: Both lists may contain references to the same objects. If you can't do that, override the element type's `Equals` method. But read the [Remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm guessing since the lists were created separately they are not the same object

You could add the very same object to two different collections, e.g.:

```
YourType obj = new YourType();
list1.Add(obj);
list2.Add(obj);
```

This should solve your issue.

You could also override the `Equals` method of `YourType` as suggested in the comments but you shouldn't have to if both collections references the same objects, which they should since the second is a subset of the first.

Comment: I ended up just creating the subset list from the exact same objects as the superset list, although I'm still running into an issue when you select an item from the subset it's not selecting the datagrid's item. However vice versa works... I even have 'UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay' so I'll try to update later when I get back to this task and figure out the issue.